# why proguard is only obfuscating the class which is not extending anything

Tags: android, security, android-proguard

i am trying to obfuscate my android application with proguard. But the problem is when i decompiled the apk it only shows the changed variable names but  class names are same as in the source.Only one class's name is changed which is not extending the any other class.I have searched many options but nothing worked so i am posting my problem here.

Here is my gradle file code:-

```
 buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

and in my proguard rules.pro file

```
-ignorewarnings
```

please help me with this
Thanks:)

Comment: try my rules.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what exactly problem in your case but i had solved my problem by below **`proguard rules`** and their are various rules which help you to protect your application

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-printmapping build/libs/output/obfuscation.map
-keepattributes
-adaptclassstrings
-dontnote
-dontwarn

# Keep Android classes
-keep class ** extends android.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Keep serializable classes & fields
-keep class ** extends java.io.Serializable {
    <fields>;
}

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** w(...);
}
```

For More Information you can visit [`Proguard official site`](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples)

Comment: Used this but class names are still there

Answer (score 2):

Use this **RULES**

It will change obfuscating the `class` as well as your `instance`

```
-ignorewarnings

-keep class * {
    public private default *;
}
```

> **Note:** Don't forget to check your all functionalities after applying changes in `proguard-ruls.pro` file

There are may be some `class` will not work after applied changes in `proguard-ruls.pro` file in this case you have to use `-keep` to avoid this issue

**-keep** Specifies classes and class members (fields and methods) to be preserved as entry points to your code. For example, in order to keep an application, you can specify the main class along with its main method.

**and you can apply this rules also**

```
ignorewarnings

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*


-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** w(...);
}
```

for more about `proguard-rules` you can refer official [**proguard DOC**](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage)