# Issue with ObjectAnimator in release APK

Tags: android, animation, proguard, objectanimator

I have done some sort of animation in my app with object animator and its working fine in debug variant. But in production, I have enabled proguard for that and it's not working as expected. I searched a lot for keeping this file in proguard, but no luck. Please help me in this.

I tried the followings

```
 -keep class ma.smartshift.loadtaker.loginv2.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers public class android.animation.ObjectAnimator {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
```

Comment: try with adding **-keep class android.animation.ObjectAnimator {;}**

Comment: sorry also try with **-keep class android.animation.ObjectAnimator { *; }**

Comment: No its not working @ND1010_

Comment: what do you want, you have to apply prooguard rules ok?

Comment: see my answer for that : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941251/why-proguard-is-only-obfuscating-the-class-which-is-not-extending-anything/47941445#47941445)

Comment: I have a similar issue, @pranavjayadev did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a rather old question, but as I stumbled upon it, I thought others might, too.

So Using Proguard is the right approach, but you exclude the wrong class.

You need to exclude the function in the target class of your `ObjectAnimator`, not the `ObjectAnimator` itself.

### Example

Let's say you have an Object animator animating the peek height of a `BottomSheetBehavior`:

```kotlin
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
    bottomSheetBehavior,
    "peekHeight",
    resources.getDimension(R.dimen.miniplayer_peek_height).toInt(),
    resources.getDimension(R.dimen.miniplayer_peek_height_anim_max).toInt()
)
```

Then you would need to add the following to your proguard rules:

```
-keep class com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior {
    setPeekHeight(int);
}
```