# Reverse Engineering made easy after adding gms:play-services-auth dependency

Tags: android

After adding gms:play-services in my build.gradle file like below:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
```

I am getting whole code of my app in reverse engineering online apk tool. How to stop it?

Comment: Did you use proguard or any similar thing ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941405/7666442

Comment: Yes i had tried proguard too. but still the same issue.

Comment: what does `gms`have to do with your project's WHOLE code?. Are you sure you're using proguard? Show your `build.gradle` release or debug section.

Comment: I had added below code in my build.gradle file:                         release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

Comment: @NileshRathod i had just tried your solution, but still getting the same issue.

Comment: @VNS so you are running when you test your apk with reverse engineering tool are you sure that you are giving it release build and not debug build. ?

Comment: @SomeshKumar yes i am trying with release apk.

Comment: I am getting my webservices URL in reverse engineering, thats why i want to hide my code.

Comment: [ http://apk-deguard.com ] this link gives my whole source code. how to stop apk from decompile?